# specific regex for getting a set of string possibilities

Tags: regex

I need to build ONE regular expression that can detect ALL the following strings and ONLY those.

```
// 'NC_' or 'NG_', can be from 6 to 9 digits after the underscore.
// '.' is static, can be 1 or 2 digits after the '.'
"NC_123456.12" or "NG_123456.12"
// Example: /^N(G|C)_[0-9]{6,9}\.[0-9]{1,2}/


// 'LRG_' is static, can be 1 or more digits after the underscore
"LRG_1234"
// Example: /LRG_[1-9][0-9]*/


// 'UD_' is static, can be 1 or more digits after the underscore
"UD_123456789012"
// Example: /UD_[0-9]+/
```

So the problem i have is not that i need the regex for finding the strings individually, but that I need ONE regex that can catch ALL the above situations. I don't know if it's even possible, but I want to thank everyone beforehand who is willing to try!

Comment: you already know about branches, so why don't you use them? am i misunderstanding your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine case 2 and three. Also, your regex for case 1 is a bit awkward.

```
/N[GC]_[0-9]{6,9}\.[0-9]{1,2}|(LRG|UD)_[0-9]+/
```

If you use a variant that supports it, you can use

```
/N[GC]_\d{6,9}\.\d{1,2}|(LRG|UD)_\d+/
```

The regex examples you give in the comments are a bit confusing. In case the number after LRG_ must not start with a 0, you have to use the following solution:

```
/N[GC]_\d{6,9}\.\d{1,2}|LRG_[1-9]\d*|UD_\d+/
```

The general principle stands: combine your branches with a `|`.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310199/how-can-i-translate-the-following-filename-to-a-regular-expression-in-python/311214#311214 will help you

Comment: Thnx this sounds most like what i need.

Comment: How is this a good answer if according to the comment in the code, LRG_ can't be followed by a 0?

Comment: @jbx: downvote is a bit harsh, no? it _very_ much depends on how you interpret the comments! the comment above the example strings is exactly the same for both cases, while the regex example differs. which one do we believe? i fixed the answer, so would you please be so kind?

Comment: OK agreed... its +1 from me now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
/^(N(G|C)_[0-9]{6,9}\.[0-9]{1,2})|(RG_[1-9][0-9]*)|(UD_[0-9]+)/
```

Comment: I thought about this, but i thought that it was not very clean to do it like this, but that the better way to do this was do something like: /^(LRG)|(UD)|(N(G|C))_[0-9]+/ More like a combination if u understand what i try to say....

Comment: Well, if you follow the rules in your code its difficult to combine them, you have a restriction that the first digit after LRG can't be 0. And the digits following NG or NC have a dot (.) between them, which the others don't.